# how to reshape 3D to 2D ? but I don't want to lose the brackets in between?

Tags: python, numpy

I have this array

```
X = np.array([[-2, -1.9], [-3, -2], [-1, -1],  [1, 1.5], [3, 2]])
```

once I insert a point

```
x = np.asarray([[20, 4.9]])
```

it becomes 3D

```
array([[[-2. , -1.9],
        [-3. , -2. ],
        [-1. , -1. ],
        [ 1. ,  1.5],
        [ 3. ,  2. ],
        [20. ,  4.9]]])
```

How to keep it always 2D even if I added points ?

Comment: In case you are looking for a method to make 3D array become a 2D one without changing element order, use [numpy.squeeze()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html). It removes "redundant" dimensions, ie: dimensions with length of 1.

Comment: Double check the `shape` of your `X` and `x`.  (You should have also shown the 'insert' call.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> X = np.array([[-2, -1.9], [-3, -2], [-1, -1],  [1, 1.5], [3, 2]])
>>> x = np.asarray([[20, 4.9]]) 
>>> np.append(X,x,axis=0)
array([[-2. , -1.9],
       [-3. , -2. ],
       [-1. , -1. ],
       [ 1. ,  1.5],
       [ 3. ,  2. ],
       [20. ,  4.9]])
>>> np.insert(X, len(X), x, axis=0)
array([[-2. , -1.9],
       [-3. , -2. ],
       [-1. , -1. ],
       [ 1. ,  1.5],
       [ 3. ,  2. ],
       [20. ,  4.9]])
```

**Edit answer base your comment:** *(Change 3D numpy.array to 2D numpy.array)*

```
>>> Y = np.array([[[-2. , -1.9], [-3. , -2. ], [-1. , -1. ], [ 1. , 1.5], [ 3. , 2. ], [20. , 4.9]]])
>>> Y.shape
(1, 6, 2)

>>> Z = Y.reshape(Y.shape[1],Y.shape[2])
>>> Z.shape
(6, 2)
```

**Update:** *(get `numpy.array` elements with another `list`)*

```
>>> X = np.array([[-2, -1.9], [-3, -2], [-1, -1],  [1, 1.5], [3, 2]])
>>> ex = [0,1,0,1] 
>>> X[np.array(ex)]
array([[-2. , -1.9],
       [-3. , -2. ],
       [-2. , -1.9],
       [-3. , -2. ]])
```

Comment: I'm doing this : np.insert(X, len(X), x, axis=0) but the bracket became 3

Comment: I don't know why it giving me 3D 
array([[[-2. , -1.9],
        [-3. , -2. ],
        [-1. , -1. ],
        [ 1. ,  1.5],
        [ 3. ,  2. ],
        [20. ,  4.9]]])

Comment: do you run and check my code? what is version of `numpy`?

Comment: I  don't think numpy is the problem though it's 1.20.1

Comment: @user4556432 `np.insert` or `np.append` don't change the shape, do you think maybe from where and give me note then maybe I can help you

Comment: how to reshape it into 2D ?

Comment: this is what I get as error : 
Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.

Comment: @user4556432 you pass 3d array to your estimator. please reshape to 2d array then pass to your estimator

Comment: once I do this action 
ex = [0,1,0,1]
 X = (X[ex !=0])
it becomes 3D .. do you know how to fix it

Comment: @user4556432 try this : `X[np.array(ex)]` and get what you want

Comment: it crashed again.. don't know what's the problem

Comment: where is your code crash?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237556/discussion-between-user4556432-and-user1740577).

Answer (score 1):

```
np.concatenate((X, x), axis=0)
```

result:

```
array([[-2. , -1.9],
       [-3. , -2. ],
       [-1. , -1. ],
       [ 1. ,  1.5],
       [ 3. ,  2. ],
       [20. ,  4.9]])
```

Comment: I'm doing this : 
np.insert(X, len(X), x, axis=0) but the bracket became 3

Comment: I just tried  "np.insert(X, len(X), x, axis=0)" on my Jupyter Notebook
and the result was:
    array([[-2. , -1.9],
       [-3. , -2. ],
       [-1. , -1. ],
       [ 1. ,  1.5],
       [ 3. ,  2. ],
       [20. ,  4.9]])
    
(Got the same result with 2 brackets.)

Comment: FYI, this is equivalent to `np.vstack((X, x))`